# Can't open deep link from browser ( js )

Tags: javascript, react-native, deep-linking

When I try to executre `window.open('nativecabinet://line/line_registration/70a4bd7d-b689-46fe-90e9-7fedc01b383f')` , I get the issue :

> line_registration:1 Failed to launch 'nativecabinet://line/line_registration/70a4bd7d-b689-46fe-90e9-7fedc01b383f' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.

It is enoying , but I can't do anything. Tried to make it by link `<a href="nativecabinet://line/line_registration/70a4bd7d-b689-46fe-90e9-7fedc01b383f">click</a>` , it also doesn't replace url in browser navigation bar . What I can I do with it ? I've found also that I can make my own `scheme` , by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler , but it only supported on `33%` of devices , and it seems not the best idea to use it . I'm out of ideas .,,

Comment: The browser is telling you that it has no idea what it's supposed to do with `nativecabinet:` links, which means that whatever is supposed to handle `nativecabinet:` links never registered that fact with your browser or your OS (which the browser will ask for help when there's scheme's it doesn't know about).

Comment: is there any way to handle it  @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans and open deep link from browser ? Maybe I can modify it somehow and make it work ? I realy to move from browser to my app

Comment: So when you are talking about react native. I assume you have an Android and/or iOS app? Did you declare that schema in your app so the system knows there is an app that can handle this schema? Also be aware that (at least with android) you cannot exclusively bind a custom schema to your app. Ie if someone else creates an app providing handlers for the same schema, the user will be presented a dialog on which app to use

Comment: I've configured my schema with https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/ , and  tested it from terminal by npx uri-scheme open nativeCabinet:// --ios and it open my app , but you are right , it doesn't open it on android by npx uri-scheme open nativeCabinet:// --android , but at least it should work on ios 
when I open browser in my simulator and pass nativeCabinet:// directly to nav line , it opens app, but it still doesn't work when I try to open it from js code

Comment: `nativeCabinet !== nativecabinet` (or it at least may be, I'm not sure as we use verified app links and not custom schemas for deep linking )

Comment: Furthermore, opening deep links from the browser typically requires a user gesture (like a click) to work. You won't be able to trigger this from JavaScript for obvious reasons (again speaking about android as I have no experience with iOS development)